# How do I inject my own classes into controllers in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I created my own class for user management called `UserManager`. I want controllers to have access to a `UserManager` object to sign in or register users.

I understand that I have to provide a parameterized constructor in the controller class that takes an object of `UserManager` and assigns it to a private attribute etc.

But **where** and **how** do I register my class in my project so that it will be injected automatically by the ASP.NET MVC Core framework?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: No offence, but did you even try to search for this?

Comment: Yes I did, and I found a lot of threads dealing with MVC but not MVC Core, or documentation like @R.Richards posted which went on and on about how to add Singletons or Interfaces, so I assumed I am looking at the wrong documentation because I assumed there is an easier solution that I am not able to find.

Comment: And I did not add what I already know, like that it all goes in Startup.cs and I have to add a service because personally if I search for an answer on Stackoverflow I like questions that are short and get to the point. Since I could not solve the problem myself all the steps that I did or I suspect are necessary are irrelevant to the next person who has this problem. It does not mean that I did not already put effort in solving the problem myself.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain in better detail the types of service registration.

Comment: Btw, why the down votes? Can you please point me to a specific sentence in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that describes a principle that my question violates? I hope it's not only "this is too easy", because this is not a criteria for asking and just because it is obvious for you it is not for others.

Comment: ASP.NET Core can't stop talking about dependency injections. It's among the biggest things they were advertising with its release. There is plenty of documentation on it if you search asp.net core dependency injection or asp.net core middleware.

Comment: @James: There is documentation about almost everything. If lack of documentation was the only allowed reason to post questions, then 95% of Stackoverflow questions would have to be deleted.

Comment: @problemofficer:  I'm not trying to say that. I'm saying some things have awful documentation in existence on some server, and some have baby-proof, step-by-step tutorials everywhere you look, and everywhere in between. It's my understanding that this exact use case leans heavily towards the baby-proof end. If I'm mistaken, so be it. My bad, I accept that. But my understanding is that it takes next to zero effort to find this answer, and stack overflow guidelines ask for a clear effort to have been made before asking a question. I do not see that effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes that are injected with dependencies usually don't use the concrete classes (`UserManager.cs`) for their constructor parameters, but rely on interfaces e.g. `IUserManager`. Although it is possible to use concrete classes, an interface provides looser coupling which is the reason for using dependency injection in the first place.

Whenever the framework encounters a constructor (in this case the constructor of the controller) that "wants" an interface it has too look up which concrete class it should use for injection.

## Where

The relationship between "class wants type X" and "framework will inject it with type Y" is defined in the `ConfigureServices` method in *Startup.cs*.

## What

#### 1. Decide on the lifetime of the created object

There are three options for defining the above relationship, that differ in the lifetime the object created by the dependency injection framework is alive.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) says:

> **Transient**
>
> Transient lifetime services are created each time they are requested.
>   This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.
>
> **Scoped**
>
> Scoped lifetime services are created once per request.
>
> **Singleton**
>
> Singleton lifetime services are created the first time they are
>   requested (or when ConfigureServices is run if you specify an instance
>   there) and then every subsequent request will use the same instance.

#### 2. Add the code

After choosing a lifetime (scoped in the following examples) you add the line

```
services.AddScoped<IInterfaceUsedByControllerParameter, ClassThatWillBeInjected>();
```

or for OPs class

```
services.AddScoped<IUserManager, UserManager>();
```

or if `UserManager` implements several interfaces:

```
services.AddScoped<ILogin, UserManager>();
services.AddScoped<IRegister, UserManager>();
```

With those two lines whenever a class requires a constructor parameter with either of those two interfaces the dependency injection will provide it with an object of type `UserManager`.

## Code examples

In case of the last example where `UserManager` implements the interfaces `ILogin` and `IRegister`:

#### Controler

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogin    _login;
        private readonly IRegister _registration;

        public UserController(ILogin login, IRegister registration)
        {
            _login = login;
            _registration = registration;
        }
...
...
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddScoped<ILogin, UserManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IRegister, UserManager>();
            ...
            services.AddMvc();
            ...
```

Comment: After reading more documentation and (hopefully) understanding how dependency injection works, I decided to add an answer myself. Imho it explains the answer more detailed and easier to understand and most importantly it explains how the two generics parameters in `AddScoped` relate or what they express. Maybe this is useful to other people who don't understand this concept, like I did.

Answer (score 9):

In the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in the `Startup.cs` class add:

```
services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
services.AddScoped<IOperationScoped, Operation>();
services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingleton, Operation>();
```

Swapping out `IOperationTransient`, `IOperationScoped` or `IOperationSingleton` for your own class / services that need injected.

There are three ways to register services for injection:

1. Transient - These services will be created each time they are requested.
2. Scoped - These services will be created once per request.
3. Singleton - These services are created once on the first request and then every subsequent request will receive the same instance.

Comment: This answer is not clear because you are using Interfaces but do not explain why. It is not clear how IOperationTransient relates to UserManager. I found it out myself in the meantime but your answer was not really helpful in that. It does explain the three types of services well though imo.

Comment: Your question was "But where and how do I register my class in my project so that it will be injected automatically by the ASP.NET MVC Core framework?", I answered that for you clearly.  Your question did not ask "How does an interface relate to a class".  The fact that you had got so far as to ask where to register the services I assumed you knew the principles of DI.